# How to pass list as a arguments to a ThreadPoolExecutor and get the index and value

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

How can I pass a list to ThreadPoolExecutor and get index and value. I tried but I am not being able to get the desired output. I want to create multithreading video converter with value and index will create separate folders and for this how can I achieve it?

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def main(videos):
    transcode = Transcode()
    for index, video in enumerate(videos):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            executor.submit(transcode.hls, video, index)
```

Comment: Is `transcode.hls()` not getting called in separate threads with `video` and `index`? It's not clear what behavior you're seeing vs. what you expect.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `Transcode` object, or at least some mock-up that replicate its behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do the same work (`transcode.hsl`) on multiple inputs stored in an `Iterable`. There is a convenience method for that:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def main(videos):
    transcode = Transcode()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        executor.map(transcode.hls, videos, range(len(videos))
```